# Change the Current date for Arshaw Full-Calender ?

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar

I am using arshaw fullcalendar api for rendering calendar. My application has client server architecture ie I have the database for my application on a server which is available on the client machiene as and when requested. 
All i want is that the server date should be reflected on client side when Today option is selected. For that i have done the following : *(only a section of code)*

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            year: runningYear, // assume 2010
            month: runningMonthNew, // assume 10
            date: runningDate, // assume 15

            columnFormat: { 
                week: 'ddd dd/MM', // Mon 9/7
                day: 'dd/MM' // Mon 9/7
            }
```

Where `runningYear,runningMonthNew and runningDate` are already defined. The date values displayed are as passed except for the `today` option on clicking on `today` the calender takes the client machine date not the server date passed. 
Please suggest a way by which i can change the date settings for the today option from `client current date` to the `Server date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make these changes in fullcalendar.js

assuming year is server year, month is server month , day is server date

replace today function with these lines.

```
function today() {
        var actServerDate = new Date(year,month,day);
        var today = actServerDate;
        date = actServerDate;
        renderView();
    }
```

in renderView() function replace

```
var today = new Date();
```

with

```
 var actServerDate = new Date(year,month,day);
 var today = actServerDate;
 date = actServerDate;
```